# Linear Algebra Done Right: why we define the inner product between two polynomials (of degree at most m) as $<p,q>=\int_{0}^1p(x)\bar{q}(x)dx$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

In Linear Algebra Done Right (2nd Edition) equation (6.2), we defined the inner product between two polynomials as $<p,q>=\int_{0}^1p(x)\bar{q}(x)dx$. I'm wondering if there is a particular reason for defining the inner product between two polynomials (with degree at most $m$) as $<p,q>=\int_{0}^1p(x)\bar{q}(x)dx$ instead of $<p,q>=\int_{a}^bp(x)\bar{q}(x)dx$ for any constants $a,b$. Seems to me that $<p,q>=\int_{a}^bp(x)\bar{q}(x)dx$ is also a legitimate inner product.

Comment: You are right but in the book they consider polynomials as functions on [0,1], hence the definition. If one considers function on [a,b] then your approach would make sense.

Comment: there is no special reason, its just an example of an inner product. This is all.

Comment: @Salcio I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks a lot! This is helpful!

Comment: Let $P(x) =p(a+(b-a)x)$ and $Q(x) =q(a+(b-a)x).$ Then $$\int\limits_a^bp(x)q(x)\,dx=(b-a)\int\limits_0^1P(x)Q(x)\,dx$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much! I guess this is probably another reason, i.e., focusing on [0,1] is without loss of generality by this change of variable argument.